# How much state data is exposed during validation by signing parties or validating notaries?

Tags: validation, corda, states

How much state data is exposed during validation by signing parties or validating notaries?

In batch processing, loading multiple states in a single transaction may improve processing performance, but the concern is any exposure to downstream parties involved in new transactions involving any of the individual states that were batched into the single transaction. How much data about all of the states in the single transaction are exposed to parties (or validating notaries) in downstream transactions?

Comment: A Previous transaction can't be passed as input but only the states can be.. Its upto us which all existing states are being passed as input to any new transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Signing parties to a transaction get full exposure to all the state data as well as being able to walk the chain and see the history of the states.

Validating notaries are also be exposed to the full state data of any states associated with the contract they run verify on.

Answer (score 0):

Cais is correct that all transaction data is exposed to signing parties and validating notaries as of Corda 3.

However, it is expected that transaction validation will be moved into SGX enclaves in a future version of Corda. This will mean that signing parties and validating notaries will be able to check that a transaction is valid without seeing its contents. See https://www.corda.net/2017/06/corda-sgx-privacy-update/.